# How to running the Java server on the Window 7

Tags: java, apache

I can't run the Java server on Win7

As a Javascript Developer, I am not familiar with Java and now am going to run the Java server on my side.
My OS is Windows 7.
For running the server, I've installed the Java SDK, Apache Ant and Apache Maven.

And then run the command following.

```
java -jar provamark-base-app.jar
```

But failed.

```
        2018-02-09 17:08:01.569  INFO 11792 --- [           main] com.provamark.Application                : Starting Application on com-PC with PID 11792 (D:\Work\Project\provamark\backend-server\provamark-base-app.jar started by Administrator in D:\Work\Project\provamark\backend-server)
    2018-02-09 17:08:01.602  INFO 11792 --- [           main] com.provamark.Application                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2018-02-09 17:08:01.823  INFO 11792 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2b71e916: startup date [Fri Feb 09 17:08:01 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (jar:file:/D:/Work/Project/provamark/backend-server/provamark-base-app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/) to
    method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    2018-02-09 17:08:06.554  INFO 11792 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14469a4d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-02-09 17:08:06.649  INFO 11792 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$acf46287] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-02-09 17:08:06.663  INFO 11792 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-02-09 17:08:06.666  INFO 11792 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@5a411614' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-02-09 17:08:06.672  INFO 11792 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d1c90539] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-02-09 17:08:06.684  INFO 11792 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-02-09 17:08:08.122  INFO 11792 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8181 (http)
    2018-02-09 17:08:08.151  INFO 11792 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
    2018-02-09 17:08:08.153  INFO 11792 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
    2018-02-09 17:08:08.611  INFO 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2018-02-09 17:08:08.612  INFO 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6849 ms
    2018-02-09 17:08:22.369  INFO 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2018-02-09 17:08:22.441  INFO 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
            name: default
            ...]
    2018-02-09 17:08:22.651  INFO 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
    2018-02-09 17:08:22.653  INFO 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    2018-02-09 17:08:22.655  INFO 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    2018-02-09 17:08:22.698 ERROR 11792 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
    Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUserDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#ea789e7' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#ea789e7': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    2018-02-09 17:08:22.993  WARN 11792 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    2018-02-09 17:08:23.077 ERROR 11792 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
            at com.provamark.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes!/:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [provamark-base-app.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [provamark-base-app.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [provamark-base-app.jar:na]
```

And to fix it, I've tried but still have issue.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the JRE version in the build path.
Try downgrading it to JRE 8 if your JRE version is 9.
Try finding out the Java version in which the JAR was built. It could be due to a major/minor version error

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer a little bit, as it currently is and by the OP's experience, he's going to have a hard time understanding at such high level

Comment: @Chisko yeah sure...... JRE is the runtime version of your java which has inbuilt jars. Major Minor version meaning that your JRE might be of version 8.0.141 but the jar you are using might be made from 8.0.121 or 8.0.111 or even lower versions

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using Java 9 and there the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` comes from because JAXB is not in the standard module.

Either use Java 8 (that's what I would recommend) or you have to add a maven dependendy to JAXB like.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I downgrade the version of Java from 9 to 8 as you want. But still fail. Should I install the Apache Tomcat too?

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace that you get now?

Comment: I fixed the above issue but got the following message now.


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8181 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8181, or configure this application to listen on another port.

Comment: The port is 8181 and checked other application already used the 8181 port.
But 8181 port is free, so not sure what the problem is.